# Error while trying to run snakemake in a venv on a protected server

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake, python-venv

For a project I made a virtual environment (venv) using Python3. I installed all the necessary dependencies using a simple bash script (see picture below) after I activated my venv. (I verified the  installed packages using: `pip3 list` and concluded that every dependency was installed succesfully.)

[image: simple bash script]

My project uses snakemake, so I ran this snakemake commando:

```
snakemake --snakefile Snakefile.py all
```

I get this error:

[image: error]

I know it has to do something with the venv, because without the venv snakemake runs perfectly. I have read the Snakemake installation documents and it says I have to install conda and make & activate a conda venv. But, I do not have the sudo privileges to download and install conda (I work on a protected server).

What is happening and does someone know a fix?

Comment: Please include the code associated with the error. I can see in your image that there is a `SyntaxError`; however, I couldn't see which file because the image was cropped.

Comment: @Salma the whole error is already shown in the picture. The last, cropped line is the command line.

Comment: Did you try to use single quotes instead of double quote when printing the job id attribute? It seems that line has the syntax error.

Comment: Solution: my python version is not compatible with the newest version of snakemake. The newest snakemake version uses f-string literal. I use python 3.5.3 which does not have f-string literal.

Comment: :) happy that you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason could be the difference in Python versions. What version of Python does the `pip3` prepare environment for?

As I can see from the picture provided, the invalid syntax may be because of the version of Python doesn't support f-strings.

Imagine the following two scenarios: when you run Snakemake manually, you use the latest Python3 (e.g. 3.9). But if the `pip3` is configured for an older version (e.g. 3.5), you can configure a very different environment for Python3.5 that doesn't support f-strings.